# How do you pass otherProps without causing a typescript interface error?

Tags: typescript

```
interface IWrapperProps {
    flag: any
    [otherProps: string]: unknown

}

const Wrapper = (props: Readonly<IWrapperProps>) => {

    const { flag, ...otherProps } = props
    return (
        <div>
            <DateTime
                {...otherProps}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

interface IDateTimeProps {
    name: string
    description: any
    value: any
}
```

I am trying to pass name, description and value as otherProps, but Typescript is throwing an error, is there a way to make this work with Typescript and while using the spread syntax trick?

I am getting the X is missing the following properties from type Y error, and the quick fix is just to pass the missing properties, but I want to do it through otherProps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` expects `name`, `description` and `value` properties. An object passed as `...props` must **at least** have all those properties. `otherProps` can, but might not have those properties. It only has an index signature which pretty much allows any property, but does not force any particular one to be set.

The easiest way to deal this would probably to change the interface `IWrapperProps` to include all the props of `IDateTimeProps`.

```
interface IWrapperProps extends IDateTimeProps {
    flag: any
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgtgDg9gTgFwAQCUCmBDAxsgZnGCJAIjkx2NFDADsE05ds0kBJAdTgyigYAUCUAM5I0AD3o0AJiNYARDPQAqkNAJjCkAb1BI9SXABsMAcwBcSDDQCeoAL5IqILDBpDknbrzhIAvEgAKKEEhC3QMKVdDawAeDi4efhCAPgBKP2TtJ30kFzdkLQNjEwAaJAA6SpgEAAskjREHf2CG3X0yBABXOBpAtpy9GKkwADdk-oGcmIVlVQnJya1K8uq6uHVhO3mFgHpxkAWkGJ3hsYnU%20yc89yQZtBUIFn8gkIt5RXvVDaF030ydA5IDrdXoBIajZLHU5pS4gah0BhMLAsd6zR7fLKAvQ0DCPCzuOC0EwTKRoIRYQlQBBgVwWKy2LFIEYYQydNB0mz2IA)

Comment: You can leave the index signature in there. Removing it changes OP's type in an incompatible way, and the intersection of a narrower type and `unknown` is just the narrower type: https://tsplay.dev/WKRxGm